# Recoding a complex composite score in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, recode

Assume my research concerns an observational longitudinal cohort study.

Let **γ_comp** be the composite outcome of interest and ****γ1**....γ4** at **time** **t1** and **t2** denote components of **γ_comp**. In addition, the dataset has three other variables (**χ1**, **χ2**, and **χ3**) which will be used in future analysis but are not necessary to code **γ_comp**. Here is an excerpt of the `data.frame`

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
                    Y1_t1 = c(5, 6, 10, 7, 5, 7, 5, 4, 7, 4), 
                    Y2_t1 = c(6, 4, 8, 8, 7, 10, 7, 6, 5, 7), 
                    Y3_t1 = c(5, 6, 10, 4, 8, 5, 10, 5, 4, 6), 
                    Y4_t1 = c(4.5, 8.5, 9.5, 4.5, 5, 8, 4.5, 8.5, 4, 6), 
                    Y1_t2 = c(6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 8, 4, 3, 2), 
                    Y2_t2 = c(5, 4, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 8), 
                    Y3_t2 = c(2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 4), 
                    Y4_t2 = c(3.5, 6, 5, 5, 4.5, 4, 2.5, 7, 4.5, 4), 
                    X1 = c(40, 45, 52, 44, 42, 65, 55, 61, 52, 49), 
                    X2 = c("NL", "UK", "NL", "US", "UK", "US", "NL", "NL", "UK", "UK"), 
                    X3 = c(2000, 2005, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2000)), 
                    class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**Structure**

```
spec_tbl_df [10 × 13] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ID   : num [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Y1_t1: num [1:10] 5 6 10 7 5 7 5 4 7 4
 $ Y2_t1: num [1:10] 6 4 8 8 7 10 7 6 5 7
 $ Y3_t1: num [1:10] 5 6 10 4 8 5 10 5 4 6
 $ Y4_t1: num [1:10] 4.5 8.5 9.5 4.5 5 8 4.5 8.5 4 6
 $ Y1_t2: num [1:10] 6 4 5 5 3 4 8 4 3 2
 $ Y2_t2: num [1:10] 5 4 3 6 5 5 5 2 2 8
 $ Y3_t2: num [1:10] 2 2 4 5 4 9 5 3 2 4
 $ Y4_t2: num [1:10] 3.5 6 5 5 4.5 4 2.5 7 4.5 4
 $ X1   : num [1:10] 40 45 52 44 42 65 55 61 52 49
 $ X2   : chr [1:10] "NL" "UK" "NL" "US" ...
 $ X3   : num [1:10] 2000 2005 2003 2000 2001 ...
```

As mentioned earlier, I am interested in calculating **γ_comp**. The rules for recording are as follows:

- 3 out of 4 components (i.e., **γ1....γ4** must have more than **20% improvement** (i.e. decrease) on numeric scale (0 - 10) [higher is worse] at **t2** compared to **t1**).
- In the "*remaining component*," there should be **no worsening of more than 20%** at **t2** compared to **t1**

I believe the following steps have to be taken to achieve this aim. First, `Y1_diff = Y1_t2/Y1_t1` must be calculated for every component. This is the proportion between two time points and should be <0.80. Next, an `if_else condition` has to be applied, which reinforces these rules and returns `1` if the rules are met and `0` if not (i.e., "responded" to treatment or not).

For example, this could be a desired **output**:

```
      ID Ycomp Y1_t1 Y2_t1 Y3_t1 Y4_t1 Y1_t2 Y2_t2 Y3_t2 Y4_t2 Y1_diff Y2_diff Y3_diff Y4_diff    X1 X2       X3
 1     1     0     5     6     5   4.5     6     5     2   3.5    1.2     0.83    0.4     0.78    40 NL     2000
 2     2     1     6     4     6   8.5     4     4     2   6      0.67    1       0.33    0.71    45 UK     2005
 3     3     1    10     8    10   9.5     5     3     4   5      0.5     0.38    0.4     0.53    52 NL     2003
 4     4     0     7     8     4   4.5     5     6     5   5      0.71    0.75    1.25    1.11    44 US     2000
 5     5     1     5     7     8   5       3     5     4   4.5    0.6     0.71    0.5     0.9     42 UK     2001
 6     6     0     7    10     5   8       4     5     9   4      0.57    0.5     1.8     0.5     65 US     2002
 7     7     0     5     7    10   4.5     8     5     5   2.5    1.6     0.71    0.5     0.56    55 NL     2003
 8     8     0     4     6     5   8.5     4     2     3   7      1       0.33    0.6     0.82    61 NL     2004
 9     9     1     7     5     4   4       3     2     2   4.5    0.43    0.4     0.5     1.13    52 UK     2001
10    10     1     4     7     6   6       2     8     4   4      0.5     1.14    0.67    0.67    49 UK     2000
```

I would appreciate any advice on recoding the composite score **γ_comp**. Alternative methods are also welcome. The idea is to use **γ_comp** in logistic regression in future analysis.

Comment: Does "improvement" mean "decrease" in score? Because NONE of your example data have 3 or more where t2 score is increased by 20% or more

Comment: Yes, improvement means decrease in score. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: okay, so if t2/t1 <0.8, this is a 20% improvement?  That is a one point drop from 2 to 1 is "improvement", but a one point drop from 10 to 9 is not improvement, because 9/10 is not <0.8. Sorry, but you need to very explicit about relative vs absolute reductions, and the definition of improvement

Comment: You are right; it should be a relative improvement, i.e., T1/T2 < 0.8 but not T2/T1

Comment: But you just said that decreasing scores means improvement!. If T1/T2 < 0.8, then T2 is greater than T1, and that is a "worsening"!!. So, I think my original T2/T1<0.8 should be correct.  By the way, my answer below matches your Y_comp in your example

Comment: Yes you are right, apolgies. Just worked it out in plain numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you, assuming my understanding is correct:

```
inner_join(
  df, 
  df %>%
    select(ID,starts_with("Y")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(!ID,names_to = c("Y","t"), names_sep="_") %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = ID:Y, names_from=t, values_from = value) %>% 
    mutate(change=1-t2/t1) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(impct = sum(change>0.2)) %>% 
    summarize(Y_comp=1*all(impct==4 | (impct==3 & min(change)>=-0.2))) 
) %>% relocate(Y_comp,.after = ID)
```

Output:

```
      ID Y_comp Y1_t1 Y2_t1 Y3_t1 Y4_t1 Y1_t2 Y2_t2 Y3_t2 Y4_t2    X1 X2       X3
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1      0     5     6     5   4.5     6     5     2   3.5    40 NL     2000
 2     2      1     6     4     6   8.5     4     4     2   6      45 UK     2005
 3     3      1    10     8    10   9.5     5     3     4   5      52 NL     2003
 4     4      0     7     8     4   4.5     5     6     5   5      44 US     2000
 5     5      1     5     7     8   5       3     5     4   4.5    42 UK     2001
 6     6      0     7    10     5   8       4     5     9   4      65 US     2002
 7     7      0     5     7    10   4.5     8     5     5   2.5    55 NL     2003
 8     8      0     4     6     5   8.5     4     2     3   7      61 NL     2004
 9     9      1     7     5     4   4       3     2     2   4.5    52 UK     2001
10    10      1     4     7     6   6       2     8     4   4      49 UK     2000
```

Explanation:

This is an inner join between `df`, and a new dataframe that contains two columns `ID` and `Y_comp`. How is this second frame created?

1. I select the columns `ID` and those starting with "Y"
2. I pivot long, and the pivot wide to get the data into a format with four columns (ID, Y, t1, and t2).
3. On each row, I estimate the change as 1-t2/t1.
4. For each ID (`group_by(ID)`), I generate a column `impt` as the number of times `change` exceeds 0.2. This is constant over `ID`
5. For each ID, I define `Y_comp` as TRUE if all of the rows have `impct==4` (i.e. all are improvements) OR, if three are improvements and the minimum in the set is not less than negative 0.2).
6. I multiply by 1 in that same line, to convert Y_comp to numeric 1/0, rather than T/F
7. After the join is completed, I move Y_comp after ID, using `relocate()`

#### Update:

The OP is having an error, likely caused by namespace collision; one solution is to be specific about the packages being used:

```
library(magrittr)
dplyr::inner_join(
  df, 
  df %>%
    dplyr::select(ID,starts_with("Y")) %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(!ID,names_to = c("Y","t"), names_sep="_") %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = ID:Y, names_from=t, values_from = value) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(change=1-t2/t1) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(impct = sum(change>0.2)) %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(Y_comp=1*all(impct==4 | (impct==3 & min(change)>=-0.2))) 
) %>% dplyr::relocate(Y_comp,.after = ID)
```

Comment: Tried the solution and got the error `Error in summarize(., Y_comp = 1 * all(impct == 4 | (impct == 3 & min(change) >=  : argument "by" is missing, with no default`. Also, I am not sure if this solution will work for me, as it seems to depend on `ID.` In my actual analysis, I want to recode variables in a `mids object` (i.e., multiply imputed datasets, 50 to be more precise) created by `mice`, which will have overlapping `IDs`.

Comment: just create any row id you want

Comment: Hi @Pashtun, I'd like to help further. did you solve your issue?  The code works on the provided structure.  If your real data is different, perhaps you could share the structure of your real data?

Comment: The error you are seeing is likely a namespace collision error. For example, perhaps you have other packages like Hmisc, or plyr loaded. You can probably solve this by restarting R, and only loading tidyverse, or you can always add the specific library in front of each function ; I've edited my answer for you

Comment: your updated solution works perfectly; thank you for your effort. I marked your answer as the correct one out of respect for the effort. I also posted my version of a solution to this problem, less elegant than yours but working.

Comment: great, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Insipired by the method of langtang, I found one **possible solution** to the problem:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Y1_diff = 
                case_when( Y1_t2/ Y1_t1 < 0.8 ~ 1,
                           Y1_t2 == 0 ~ 0,
                           Y1_t2/ Y1_t1 >= 0.8 & Y1_t2/ Y1_t1 <=1.2 ~ 0, 
                           TRUE ~ -1)) %>%
  mutate(Y2_diff = 
           case_when( Y2_t2/ Y2_t1 < 0.8 ~ 1,
                      Y2_t2 == 0 ~ 0,
                      Y2_t2/ Y2_t1 >= 0.8 & Y2_t2/ Y2_t1 <=1.2 ~ 0, 
                      TRUE ~ -1)) %>%
  mutate(Y3_diff = 
           case_when( Y3_t2/ Y3_t1 < 0.8 ~ 1,
                      Y3_t2 == 0 ~ 0,
                      Y3_t2/ Y3_t1 >= 0.8 & Y3_t2/ Y3_t1 <=1.2 ~ 0, 
                      TRUE ~ -1)) %>%
  mutate(Y4_diff = 
           case_when( Y4_t2/ Y4_t1 < 0.8 ~ 1,
                      Y4_t2 == 0 ~ 0,
                      Y4_t2/ Y4_t1 >= 0.8 & Y4_t2/ Y4_t1 <=1.2 ~ 0, 
                      TRUE ~ -1)) %>%
  mutate(Ycomp = 
           case_when(Y1_diff+Y2_diff+Y3_diff+Y4_diff >=3 ~ 1,
                     TRUE ~ 0))
```

**Explanation**

I am creating four variables first, which assess whether the relative difference was less than 0.8 (i.e., 20% improved), between 0.8-1.2, or worsened and was more than >1.2. In the case of improvement, these between variables (Yn_diff) were coded +1, +0 if in between, and -1 if worsened. I also looked if, at time **t2**, the variable output was zero and gave it a score of 0 because, in my real dataset, there were scenario's where both **t1** and **t2** were 0, which gives **NaaN** error. Finally, I added up all the variables, which gives the correct output in the variable Ycomp.

**Output**

```
      ID Ycomp Y1_t1 Y1_t2 Y2_t1 Y2_t2 Y3_t1 Y3_t2 Y4_t1 Y4_t2
 1     1     0     5     6     6     5     5     2   4.5   3.5
 2     2     1     6     4     4     4     6     2   8.5   6  
 3     3     1    10     5     8     3    10     4   9.5   5  
 4     4     0     7     5     8     6     4     5   4.5   5  
 5     5     1     5     3     7     5     8     4   5     4.5
 6     6     0     7     4    10     5     5     9   8     4  
 7     7     0     5     8     7     5    10     5   4.5   2.5
 8     8     0     4     4     6     2     5     3   8.5   7  
 9     9     1     7     3     5     2     4     2   4     4.5
10    10     1     4     2     7     8     6     4   6     4
```